# Ajax file upload with formData fails on some files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

file upload with jQuery+formData and php works fine with some files. But on other, I think larger files it seems the file is cuted or something. The $_POST and $_FILES arrays are empty. I tried lot of things, but nothing helps.

Here the form:

```
    <form id="myform"  method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" id="file-documents" name="file" class="hidden">
    </form>
```

and js code:

```
        var form = $('#myform')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);
        data.append('job', 'upload_file');

     $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // 
        success: function(data) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

I see following in the firebug request:

Source
-----------------------------15933312197684
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ganz alt.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed

PK����êPEëøz    ýtQ�ù¥X����20140728164446766.pdfÄZù_×PÍ!âÆ�AÙTG¥dµJÀ²FÔ¥-¶QÁAÐÙJ
 ì"­
®EQµ    `­U|¶}ïÄ÷þ÷î½sï9ç~Ï÷|ÏØùø9»¬\£o[V­ïfµÚjL¢þÆ«"¾J[½%&1Kê¯ÚÆ!5Rö~§¿j{B,oµf«
þ*ÿ¸/âI+·µëÖé¯b%ÂâûSR÷óâx¤þ*bòþÛR÷rãVùÄNàÆm>¸÷+ýU~  ÉdÜAÎ*ðÛæÇÝ·KÕ  Û{0ågãFÍt~

...

-----------------------------15933312197684
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="job"

upload_file
-----------------------------15933312197684--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase your max post file size. Open up your php.ini file and find the variables `post_max_size = 8M` and `upload_max_filesize = 2M`. Change the values to 16M or however large you need. Be careful not to make it any larger than you really need to though.